# how can I see the movies via my old laptop, please ?

Tags: windows, memory, video

I have an old laptop, and I want to see movies with that, but the problem is, always in the middle of movies it's stuck and play,like the youtube movies, when your connection speed is low, maybe it's happening because of buffer, I don't know ?!

my windows is server 2003, and my ram is 512mb
I check it with several player like kmplayer and gomplayer
is there anyway to fix this ?

for example clean the ram(cache) after every 5 minutes? how ?

Comment: Simple solution -- you need more RAM.

Comment: 512Mb is just not enough to run the OS, your backround processes _and_ hold a movie in memory.  I'd also be concerned that a laptop with only 512MB may be from an era that didn't have the processing power required as well.  Have you tried disabling all non-essential background services and processes and see if it can then play them?

Comment: @techie007, thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work too :(

Answer (score 1):

I see a two problems with this scenario:

- You have have hardware that is not powerful enough to stream online video.
- You have excessive buffering and "slow connection problems, which means your bandwidth is likely insufficient to stream video.

If you are not willing to accept that the hardware  and network are incapable of  doing what you want them to do, you're out of luck.

Here is your only option:

- Upgrade or replace the legacy hardware
- Upgrade the internet bandwidth to support intense activities like video streaming

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is undersized. Put the maximum RAM you could fit in there. Google your model to find out. Most likely you can fit 2gb of RAM in there. Change you resolution lower, to something like 600x800. The less pixels it has to control the less it has to work & consume resources. On the lower setting your icons, apps, & text might look too big, but there are settings in Windows to just make them smaller at the lower resolution. You can also set the display settings down to 16 bit 800x600 if you don't mind a slightly less than perfect picture.

You OS isn't compatible with modern flash & players. Get windows XP or Windows 7 in it. Sometimes you can get old dead computers to get the OS & license off of it. You can also use a light free Linux OS like Lubuntu or Xubuntu. A 2012 version should work well in the older machine.

Your internet speed or incompatible flash player may not be fast enough. With downloadhelper or other video downloaders, you can download & save the video rather than watch the video, then just play it back later. Your VLC media player will then play the video. With VLC, you can play the video when it's only downloaded halfway, while the rest of the video continues to download, so you usually don't have wait for the entire video to download.

You will have half the video already loaded as a nice large buffer, & completely get around the buggy & resource hungry flash player.

If you go to Windows 7, go to services & disable all services you don't need or your machine can't use well to streamline the OS. With Linux, don't install any more apps & crap than you really need.

My 1.8ghz single core AMD laptop from 2005 with 768mb (0.768gb) of RAM played movies up to 720p fine running XP, Windows 7, & Xubuntu. But now I'm up to 1.5gb of RAM on it to speed other things up on it. You will not be able to get it to play 1080p video though because your laptop cannot be fitted with a good video card, & wouldn't be compatible with modern ones anyway.

An SSD (solid state drive) will also boost performance, but that machine won't support it & SSD TRIM properly. With the massive amount of file-swap required for the SSD, it would probably wear out in a few months or year. That older machine may only have a 4200rpm drive in it. By upgrading to a 5200rpm drive you'll have a significant performance boost. The RPMs may not be much faster, but the newer 5200rpm drive has more data per square inch on the platter than those old 4200rpm ones. So you're almost doubling drive access speeds. Also the newer drive has a bigger cache at 8mb or higher for better performance, were the old 4200 one may not have any cache at all or utilize some of the RAM as cache.

Also avoid drives above 500gb. Drives below 500gb tend to have only a single platter with lots of data per square inch for fast access. The larger drives are multiple platters, less data per inch, so slower to access.

You can also go to a 7200rpm drive, but in most cases the difference between a 5200rpm & 7200rpm one may be barely noticeable, where the difference in a 4200rpm & 5200rmp drive will be very significant. So save a few bucks if you have to with a 5200rpm one.

That old machine may be a PATA (also called IDE) drive. So make sure you don't get a modern SATA drive, because it won't work.

-PSK Research-

Comment: By the time you've upgraded all of those components, it would probably be cheaper, easier (where are you going to find a copy of Windows 7, for example?) and more effective to just buy a new low-end laptop, which would be plenty good enough for playing movies.

Answer (score 0):

your Laptop Ram is too small if you use Kmplayer Try this: right click on screen go to Options and check Advanced menu then go to video(Advanced) and select Present:Speed(1GHz) this make The Kmplayer to reduce the Quality of video and Speed it up.

Comment: I check that, it doesn't work ! :(